# batch renaming of multiple files of same extension

Tags: bash, shell

I need to rename multiple files without knowing the filename(basename/string name ) of the file.

i tried with:

```
for i in $(ls /Users/Destiny/Desktop/Index/*.ebwt); 
do 
    mv -v "$i" "${i/hsa/hsa.genome.V86C}"; ## works when i know the string to replace
done
```

but what if dont know the filename(string name)?

**Before rename:** hsa.1.ebwt  hsa.2.ebwt  hsa.3.ebwt  hsa.4.ebwt

**After rename:** hsa.genome.V86C.1.ebwt  hsa.genome.V86C.2.ebwt  hsa.genome.V86C.3.ebwt  hsa.genome.V86C.4.ebwt

Comment: then rename it to a random number :D

Comment: What are you renaming it to? The same but with a different suffix?

Comment: I am asking this  because i just know the extension of the file and i need to rename of with soemthing to use it in different bash script.

Comment: On another note, [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: `prename 's/hsa/hsa.genome.V86C/' /Users/Destiny/Desktop/Index/*.ebwt` ?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other questions that pop up if you search for `[bash] rename`?

Comment: What do your filenames look like and how are they supposed to look afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with a find in your directory. And if they all have the same extension then it could be something like below with your move that you currently have:

```
find /Users/Destiny/Desktop/Index -type f -name "*.ebwt" | while read file; 
do 
mv -v "$file" "${file/hsa/hsa.genome.V86C}"; 
done
```

This will rename it inside of the current directory, and if you want to move it to a different directory later down the line, you could surround second argument like this with basename to make moving easier:

```
"/SomeDirectory/$(basename ${file/hsa/hsa.genome.V86C})"
```

You could also put a `-maxdepth 1` after the directory you want to find if you dont want it to be recursive in the find